# How to bind 3rd Party JSON result to Existing Knockout Viewmodel

Tags: json, knockout.js

I have an existing view model that lists currency codes that I want the conversion rates for. I utilize the Yahoo Finance API to get a JSON result for my Currencies.

How do I bind this 3rd Party JSON result to my existing ViewModel.

JSON from Yahoo Finance API:

```
parseExchangeRate({"query":{"count":1,"created":"2013-01-17T07:37:18Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"row":{"rate":"8.7967","name":"USD to ZAR"}}}});
```

My Viewmodel Code:

```
    var currency = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.CurrencyFrom = ko.observable(data.CurrencyFrom);
        self.CurrencyTo = ko.observable(data.CurrencyTo);
        self.ConversionRate = ko.observable(getRate(data.CurrencyFrom, data.CurrencyTo));
    }

    var CurrencyModel = function (Currencies) {
        var self = this;
        self.Currencies = ko.observableArray(Currencies);

        self.AddCurrency = function () {
            self.Currencies.push({
                CurrencyFrom: "",
                CurrencyTo: "",
                ConversionRate: ""
            });
        };

        self.RemoveCurrency = function (Currency) {
            self.Currencies.remove(Currency);
        };

        self.Save = function (Form) {
            alert("Could Now Save: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.Currencies));
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "CurrencyConfiguration.aspx/GetConfiguredCurrencies",
            // Current Page, Method  
            data: '{}',
            // parameter map as JSON  
            type: "POST",
            // data has to be POSTed  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            // posting JSON content      
            dataType: "JSON",
            // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)  
            timeout: 10000,
            // AJAX timeout  
            success: function (Result) {
                var MappedCurrencies =
              $.map(Result.d,
       function (item) { return new currency(item); });
                self.Currencies(MappedCurrencies);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    };

    //3rd Party JSON result
    function getRate(from, to) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('src', "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D" + from + to + "%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json&callback=parseExchangeRate");
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var VM = new CurrencyModel();
        ko.applyBindings(VM);
    })
```

My HTML:

```
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Date Updated
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Currency From
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Currency To
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Conversion Rate
                    </th>
                    <th />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Currencies">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="label">Date</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind="value: CurrencyFrom, uniqueName: true" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind="value: CurrencyTo, uniqueName: true" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind="value: ConversionRate, uniqueName: true" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.RemoveCurrency'>Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My JSON Return:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"Finance.Tracntrace.Members_Only.DAL.DataModel.Currency.CurrencyConfigurationDM","CurrencyFrom":"ZAR","CurrencyTo":"USD","Rate":null},{"__type":"Finance.Tracntrace.Members_Only.DAL.DataModel.Currency.CurrencyConfigurationDM","CurrencyFrom":"USD","CurrencyTo":"ZAR","Rate":null}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got to admit, I'm not 100% sure what you actually are asking, but I presume that you are after an implementation of the parseExchangeRate you are using as the jsonp callback method?

In your case, you'll need to dive into that Yahoo return object to get the name property (query.results.row.name at a guess) and split that string to get your two currencies.

```
function parseExchangeRate(yahooData)
{
    var currencies = yahooData.query.results.row.name;

    // split the string to get your two currencies
    var from = whatever;
    var to = whatever;
    var rate = yahooData.query.results.row.rate;
```

I'd then change your AddCurrency method to take a data object

```
    CurrencyModel.AddCurrency(from, to, rate);
}

    self.AddCurrency = function (from, to, rate) {
        self.Currencies.push({
            CurrencyFrom: from,
            CurrencyTo: to,
            ConversionRate: rate
        });
    };
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, your Jquery works perfectly thanks. Just a bit unsure how to implement it.

Comment: If you're still struggling, you could put a jsfiddle together, and I'll be happy to look at it.